# Joining 02 tables on bigquery with github dataset

Tags: google-bigquery, github-api

My goal is to join `sample_contents` with `sample_commits` by `repo_name`

1) First I joined `sample_contents` with `files` so that It now contains `repo_name`

```
SELECT line,a.id,sample_path,sample_repo_name,repo_name
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT (SPLIT(content, '\n')) line , a.id,sample_path,sample_repo_name,repo_name
          FROM (
               (SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents]   WHERE sample_path LIKE '%.java' )              
               ) a JOIN  ( SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files] ) b ON a.id=b.id
        ) WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(line, '^String|^private int|^public|[.]') 
  )
```

2) Now , I did the following `query` expecting to get all commits for any given files by `repo_name`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN line CONTAINS 'String' THEN 'String' ELSE '' END) AS column_1,
(CASE WHEN line CONTAINS 'public' THEN 'public' ELSE '' END) AS column_2,line,a.id,sample_path,sample_repo_name,X.repo_name
FROM (
   SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT (SPLIT(content, '\n')) line , a.id,sample_path,sample_repo_name,repo_name
          FROM (
               (SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_contents]   WHERE sample_path LIKE '%.java' )              
               ) a JOIN  ( SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.files] ) b ON a.id=b.id
        ) WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(line, '^String|^private int|^public|[.]') 
  )
  X JOIN (SELECT * FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.sample_commits]) Y ON X.repo_name=Y.repo_name LIMIT 100
```

[image]
But It returns 0 result!
Could you help me figure out this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm getting a little lost... what's the final goal of these queries?

Comment: To track "state" of each java code per      repo per commit

Comment: 'state'? not sure still...

Comment: What I mean is for example before a commit , there were 10 lines of code, after 15 lines then I want to track exactly which changes ( one more 'if' , n-more primitives, etc..)

Comment: oh, that sounds like a very interesting query to solve (but I can't attempt it for now... but I'd love to)

Comment: Here is another attempt but It tooks forever to run: https://gist.github.com/RanaivosonHerimanitra/3345e25866d1e9af93d8b09ced825744

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, but a good place to check is the "Explanation" tab.

[image]

Notice that on the initial stages the query is processing ~2 billion rows in stage 2 and ~1.7 billion rows in stage 7. Somehow that gets translated to 10 billion rows in stage 37 (exploding JOIN or SPLIT()?).

Look at what happens on stage 37... because no row from those 10 billion passes the filters (either the WHERE or the equality JOIN):

[image]